# Dynamic coloring cells in libreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a table of percentages:

```
    A  |  B  |  C
-------------------
1| 12% | 22% | 42% 
-------------------
2| 52% |  2% | 82% 
-------------------
3| 72% | 32% | 92%
```

Is it possible to create a colour map (like a heat map) based on the values in the cells? 0% is pure green and 100% is pure red

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the cell color according to the value with:

```
Format > Conditional Formatting
```

For more info, you can visit : [Applying Conditional Formatting](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Applying_Conditional_Formatting)